# have I added enough to get question re-opened?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I've added information to a question to see if that is enough to get it re-opened.

[standby only at login screen?](https://serverfault.com/questions/300470/standby-only-at-login-screen-closed)

Is it enough information or do I need to add more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently [Sam](https://serverfault.com/users/48/sam) thinks so.